# Convert byte[] to Image EmguCV without know width and height

Tags: java, image, emgucv

I need convert byte array (`byte[]`) (from java `BufferedImage`) to EmguCV Image without to know the width and height.

```
byte[] bytes = [data];
Image<Gray, byte> image = new Image<Gray, byte>();
image.Bytes = bytes;
```

Can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this
[ http://www.emgu.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=1057 ]

```
public Image<Bgr, Byte> byteArrayToImage(byte[] byteArrayIn)
{
 MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(byteArrayIn);
 Bitmap returnImage = Image.FromStream(ms);

 return new Image<Bgr, byte>(returnImage);
 // you probably need to clean up stuff like the bitmap and the stream...
}
```

On the emgu forum and retyped it to remove a variable-name typo. Assuming your byte array is a standard image , looks like you can load it into a standard image variable that will automatically figure out sizing. From there you could pass that image to the constructor of your emgu image.

Comment: Works fine!!! But it's necessary add cast from Image to Bitmap as:

    Bitmap returnImage = (Bitmap)Image.FromStream(ms);